# Why my keyword search service is incomplete?

Tags: server

I want to use the sharepoint search service to search content in some specific lists. However, some of those columns and items cannot be searched.

Let me list some problems,

1. some items cannot be found. for example, row A and row B has the same value in columnX, but only row B can be found (the result only shows 1 item). my query: `columnXMap:"*theValue*"`.
2. some columns cannot be used to search. The possible reason should be the mapping name of the column is `ows_admin/user`. I am not sure will the slash bring any error or not even i set the Property name to `AdminORuser` in search service. my query: `AdminORuser:*`.

Moerover, I had finished a Full Crawling and the Crawl Log has no error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wildcard operator (*) in KQL is supported only at the end of the phrase. [Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx#Anchor_1).
2. Ensure that managed properties for these columns are set as Queryable. [Read more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.16).aspx).